# How do I unminimize a weston window?

Tags: arch-linux, wayland

I accidentally minimized a weston-terminal window under Weston, and I want to get it back. This window is running vim with my full development environment, so I don't *want* to replace it.
By default, Weston's toolbar along the top does not have a window list, so I can't just click on that to restore it. Searching around, I found [weston-taskbar](https://github.com/Tarnyko/weston-taskbar), which hasn't been updated for the last four years. I could not find anything else about restoring minimized weston windows, so either this is a non-issue for everyone else, or there is something I am missing. `ps -eH` shows that there is still a weston-terminal running vim, so the program is still running, but there is no window shown. How can I get that window back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weston uses the Super (windows) key as the default binding modifier. So you can use Super + Tab to switch between windows. See the [Usage](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wayland#Usage) section in the Arch Linux wiki for more key bindings.

To change the default behaviour, you could set the binding-modifier value of the  compositor in [weston.ini](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/weston.ini.5#SHELL_SECTION). e.g:

```
[shell]
binding-modifier=alt
```

Comment: This is a lot more trouble when running a nested weston for debugging. Gnome's own compositor intercepts all of those (super+tab, alt+tab etc.)